# Visual Studio Performance problems when writing XAML

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've dealt with Visual Studio performing terrible for too long now. Now I'm past the point of being emotionally broken and need help.

I can't figure out how to fix the issue of the Visual Studio XAML editor performing so badly.

When I type a set of characters each one takes at least a second to appear. SOMETIMES it works ok and randomly goes back to performing terribly.

I've had this problem on separate machines with VS 2010 and 2012. I've also disabled ReSharper and the xaml designer view and still no relief.

Here's a video of what I'm dealing with: http://youtu.be/KOADBKMIr7U

Comment: Run Process Explorer in background and look if the CPU is busy.

Comment: Have you used ProcExp?

Comment: "This video is unavailable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fix I've found was using vs2013 with update 2.

Answer (score 10):

Some tips from [Disable the XAML designer in Visual Studio](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/) :

1. **Default to full XAML view**
   In the Tools –> Options menu, open the Text Editor node, then the XAML node, then select the Miscellaneous node; make sure that under the Default View heading there is a checkbox beside "Always open documents in full XAML view".
2. **Kill the designer rendering process**
   Open the Task Manager, right-click on XDesProc.exe, and select End Process.
3. **Open as source code**
   Right-click on any .xaml file in your solution explorer and select "Open With…",
   pick the "Souce Code (Text) Editor" and click "Set as Default..".

Other tips from
[XAML Editor Extraordinarily Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037468/visual-studio-2010-xaml-editor-extraordinarily-slow) :

1. **Delete the Solution User Options (.suo) file**
   This file is usually located in the same folder as the solution (.sln) file
   (better keep a backup of it).
2. **Delete the "Licenses.Licx" file**
   This file is found in the Project Properties folder (better keep a backup).

The article
[Responsive XAML editing with ReSharper](http://blog.lebosquain.net/2012/08/responsive-xaml-editing-with-resharper/) shows how to turn off IntelliSense
and use a ReSharper plugin instead.

The article
[Visual Studio Silverlight XAML designer very slow](http://nuxtech.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/visual-studio-silverlight-xaml-designer.html)
recommends deleting the `Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.WindowsAzure.dll` assembly.

I have also seen recommendations to use the Blend XAML designer/editor instead of that of VS.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 there are no "Always open documents in full XAML view" checkbox in the option pane you mention. There's a rooted XAML Designer option node in which you can set the default document view to be "Source View" but that doesn't seem to affect performance in any way.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015, there's also no XDesProc.exe process.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to try (if you haven't already)...

1. Disable "Visual Experience". Goto Tools-> Options-> Environment-> General, untick everything in the visual experience section
2. Disable auto complete. Goto Tools-> Options-> Text Editor-> [langauge you use]-> General, untick everything in "Statement completion"
3. Disable word wrap. Goto same as #2 but untick "Word Wrap". I have read that it can slow down intellsense

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable Resharper in case you have it and/or all other plugins for VS. Determine which one causes the issue and try to reinstall it. This approach has worked for me.

Comment: Which one was the "bad guy"?

Comment: @carsten-schütte For me it was Resharper. I'm still working with it and the problem does appear sometimes. When I need to work intensively with XAML I usually just disable it or start the Visual Studio in a Safe Mode. You can try to start Visual Studio in Safe Mode either to see if it works for you. Just add flag /SafeMode to the VS shortcut and run.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015, go to `Tools->Options->XAML Designer`, and uncheck "Enable XAML Designer"